# Did the hyoid bone of Australipetichus afarensis have a hyoid bulla?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution, anthropology

The hyoid bulla is present in Chimpanzee hyoid bones, and not in Humans. Does A. afarensis have a hyoid bulla?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes.

**Longer but still short answer:**

*H. heidelbergensis* and *H. neanderthalensis* have a modern human-like hyoid bone. *A. afarensis* has a hyoid bulla similar to modern chimpanzees.

The [hyoid bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyoid_bone) is thought by some to be important in human evolution because of its position in the throat and the possibility that morphological changes in the hyoid were important for the development of speech. However, this view is not without controversy, and it is probably not sufficient to use hyoid bone morphology as a *definitive* marker for development of speech similar to modern humans, though it may be suggestive.

Some quotes from two references on the morphology of the hyoid of *A. afarensis*:

Alemseged, et al. 2006:

> [the hyoid of *A. afarensis*] "...is
>   most similar to that of juvenile African apes, and unlike that of
>   modern humans11,12. The exposed greater horn is slender, and the
>   body is expanded anteriorly, forming a bulla that is deep relative to its
>   breadth and height..."

Steele, et al. 2013:

> "...the Dikika juvenile australopith hyoid is deep for its height (Figure 9) and width and is morphologically chimpanzee-like. This similarity applies both when comparing only subadults from the three extant species (Figure 9A), and when comparing across all observed age classes (Figure 9B..."

---

References:

Alemseged, Z., Spoor, F., Kimbel, W. H., Bobe, R., Geraads, D., Reed, D., & Wynn, J. G. (2006). A juvenile early hominin skeleton from Dikika, Ethiopia. Nature, 443(7109), 296-301.

Steele, J., Clegg, M., & Martelli, S. (2013). Comparative morphology of the hominin and african ape hyoid bone, a possible marker of the evolution of speech. Human biology, 85(5), 639-672.

Comment: Is the A. afarensis hyoid bone in the Steele, Clegg, Martelli paper, from Selam (the 3 year old, aka "baby lucy") found in Dikika ? That's the only fossil remnant of an A. ararensis hyoid bone I've come across (https://www.nature.com/article-assets/npg/nature/journal/v443/n7109/images/nature05047-f3.2.jpg)

From the image, it's difficult to make out a hyoid bulla, and the Steele, Clegg, Martelli paper mentions that they "interpret the morphology", would you happen to know if they go by indirect evidence, and if so, what?

Comment: The Dikika specimen was a child also, 3 years old, and child hyoid bones have different proportions than adult ones (https://boneclones.com/images/store-product/product-223-main-main-big-1418687938.jpg)

Comment: I think that paper will be the best you get for an answer - as you say, if there are no other fossils, you aren't going to magically find one on Biology.SE. Steele et al. compare the Dikika sample to juveniles of the extant apes. The line about "interpret the morphology" has nothing to do with the type of evidence they used, they are just referring to comparison of all of the extinct samples with the extant species they studied.

Comment: A quote from the paper in case you cannot access it: "...the Dikika juvenile australopith hyoid is deep for its height (Figure 9) and width and is morphologically chimpanzee-like. This similarity applies both when comparing only subadults from the three extant species (Figure 9A), and when comparing across all observed age classes (Figure 9B..."

Comment: If the extinct sample is one, and its this one https://www.nature.com/article-assets/npg/nature/journal/v443/n7109/images/nature05047-f3.2.jpg

are details, like the hyoid bulla, preserved? just by looking at it, it looks like its not protruding at the anterior end, http://i.imgur.com/BYdjvHx.jpg

Comment: It looks to me like it is, clearly moreso than a modern human of the same age (from the article I referenced). Note also that your reference refers to it as a bulla as well. It's possible there is some disagreement in the field, but I see two published sources that agree with each other and no evidence otherwise.

Comment: the Steele paper says that "and one (represented by the body only) from the Dikika Australopithecus afarensis (Alemseged et al. 2006)"

while the Alemseged says "the exposed greater horn is slender, and the body is expanded anteriorly, forming a bulla that"

are they not contradicting one another? how can the greater horn be exposed, if only the hyoid body was in the fossil?

Comment: @homonidae I can't speak for the authors, but my guess is that Steele is referring to inclusion in their own *quantitative* analysis, and by their quantitative analysis only the body was fully present for quantification (I agree with you this is not clear in the statement you quoted). The qualitative description by Alemseged would not have that limitation (and Alemseged's own quantification also was based on the body I believe). All that said, your question is about a feature of the body, so I'm not sure why the presence of the horn is particularly relevant.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing about the fossil record. 

The airsacs, as resonance organs, would have de-evolved as a pharyngeal acoustic chamber formed with the descent of the larynx. 

I'm also interested in the semi-aquatic ape theory, and that the larynx descended for inhaling large amounts of air while surfacing. In that universe, the loss of airsacs could have been a later adaptation, as the expanded pharyngeal tract formed an acoustic resonance chamber.